# ATK4 CRUD: Lookup reference table for data insertion

Tags: atk4

I have elements of certain types.
I have bins of certain types.
An element only belongs in the bin of the same type.

One table in the DB contains the elements.
Another table contains the bins.
They each have a "type_id".

As far as the elements are concerned there are a few models, each of which sets ->addCondition('type', '=', 'x') in addition to the abstract base model.

Now when instantiating a CRUD of element of type X, when adding or editing items, how do I prevent bins with type Y from being shown in the dropdowns?

In essence I would like to impose an additional condition on hasOne() which restricts the foreign values shown.

```
class AbstractElement extends \atk4\data\Model {
  public $table = 'element';
  public $id_field = 'element_id';
  public $title_field = 'element_data';

  function init() {
    parent::init();

    $this->hasOne('Bin', [Bin::class, 'our_field'=>'element_bin_id', 'caption'=>'Bin', 'required'=>true])->addTitle(['caption'=>'Bin']);
    $this->addField('element_data', ['required'=>true]);
    $this->hasOne('Type', [Type::class, 'our_field'=>'type_id']);
  }
}
class Element extends AbstractElement {
  function init() {
    parent::init();
    $this->addCondition('type_id', '=', '1');
  }
}

class Bin extends \atk4\data\Model {
  public $table = 'bin';
  public $id_field = 'bin_id';
  public $title_field = 'bin_name';

  function init() {
    parent::init();

    $this->addField('bin_name', ['caption'=>'Name']);
    $this->hasOne('Type', [Type::class, 'our_field'=>'bin_type_id']);
  }
}

class Type extends \atk4\data\Model {
  public $table = 'type';
  public $id_field = 'type_id';
  public $title_field = 'type_name';

  function init() {
    parent::init();

    $this->addField('type_name');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work.

In `Type` class add:

```
$this->hasMany('Bins', [Bin::class, 'their_field'=>'bin_type_id']);
```

In `AbstractElement` class use callback to define Bin hasOne relation:

```
$this->hasOne('Bin', [
    function($m){
        return $m->ref('Type')->ref('Bins');
    },
    'our_field' => 'element_bin_id',
    'caption' => 'Bin',
    'required' => true,
])->addTitle(['caption'=>'Bin']);
```

Comment: Wow amazing, that indeed does it. Thank you, sir. Would you care to elaborate in a few words what is happening? I'll try first.

So instead of passing a static reference to some model, we give it a function which each time takes the model instance currently under consideration and first links it to its Type (which filters out the other types) and therefore results in the correct Bins on the second reference?

I'll have to get my head around these callbacks.... I have the feeling that keeps me from using this at its full potential.

Comment: Yes it works exactly as you said - instead of static reference it will call calback method each time when ref('Bin') is called.
Only situation which is a bit tricky is when creating new Element record. You shouldn't use ref('Bin') before you set type_id for Element.